# Script location execution

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I've been working on a script but always with a fixed directory (/opt/mw/script).
I need to change that to be able to execute the script from any directory.
I think I will need to add a "." at the beginning of the line to be able to execute the script?
For example ./mw/script 
Is this correct?
Thanks

Comment: I also need to put the script in any path.

Comment: If you need to have the script in any path without using the absolute file path you can put the directory in your PATH variable.Look [here](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm). Also be careful as you can cause quite a few problems if you get it wrong,

Answer (score 1):

You already *can* execute that script from any directory with that absolute file path. It's the relative file paths (that start with `./` or `../`) that can only be executed from a specific directory.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.
But I also need to be able to put the script in any path. Sorry, I think I forgot to put it in the comments

Comment: So make all your paths relative to the script directory *in* the script itself and execute your script with an absolute file path.

Answer (score 0):

You *need* to add the "." if the script is in the current directory (e.g. `./script`), but it is *optional* if the script is already inside another directory (e.g. `mw/script`).

Also notice that if your script contains relative references to other files and directories, you may need to use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in) to properly refer to them from any directory.

For instance, consider the following script using absolute paths:

```
#!/bin/bash

# lists all files in this directory
ls /opt/mw
```

If it is converted to relative paths as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# lists all files in this directory
ls mw
```

Then this script will only work if you run it from its own directory (e.g. `cd /opt/ && ./script`).

But then you can generalize it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
# lists all files in this directory
ls $SCRIPT_DIR/mw
```

Now the script works even when executed from another directory.